# mysql datetime problem "Incorrect datetime value" and daylight savings

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a problem storing a date/time. i.e.

DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Incorrect datetime value: '2022-03-27 01:00:00' for column `smets2`.`electricity`.`time`

Now the only possible thing I can see wrong with this is that perhaps this time does not exist because of daylight savings. 01:00:00 became 02:00:00

Here's the SQL I used to create the table

create table if not exists electricity
(time timestamp null,
consumption double);

So my question are ...

1. does mysql understand about daylight savings by default ?
2. What is the correct date/time for this time. Clearly it cannot be '2022-03-27 01:00:00', should it be '2022-03-27 02:00:00'
3. how can I force mysql to use UTC for date/time

Thanks

Comment: What timezone is your MySQL server using?

Comment: BST (British Summer Time) - at least I assume it is, because that's the timezone of the computer it is on.

Comment: Most likely a timezone issue since `2022-03-27 01:00:00` does not exist in BST. And yes, MySQL with (proper setup) is timezone aware. My next question would be what timezone does `2022-03-27 01:00:00` represent?

Comment: It represents a UTC (GMT) date/time. So how do I get UTC date/times into a database running on a BST machine.

Answer (score 2):

OK.

It seems that the problem is that I defined the field a 'timestamp' when it should have been 'datetime'.

'timestamp' fields get the timezone applied on input/output.

Won't make that mistake again :-)